# postgresql count distinct on differect condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I'm stuck on an exercise where I need to count the total amount of unique visits to planets, but if the planet is the moon (maan), then it should be counted twice. Also the client number should be 121

```
select case 
        when objectnaam = 'Maan' then count(objectnaam)
        else count(distinct objectnaam)
   end as aantal_bezoeken
from klanten inner join deelnames on klanten.klantnr = deelnames.klantnr
         inner join reizen on deelnames.reisnr = reizen.reisnr
         inner join bezoeken on reizen.reisnr = bezoeken.reisnr
where klanten.klantnr = 121
group by objectnaam
```

And it gives me this result

```
aantal_bezoeken
      1
      4
      1
      1
```

but the result should be

```
aantal_bezoeken
      7
```

I just need to add all these values together but I don't know how to,
or maybe there's a better more simple solution. It should be without subqueries

Comment: 1) Do you use mysql or postgresql? 2) add sample source data in text format and expected eventually result

Comment: @VaoTsun no aggregation functions can't be nested

Comment: @OtoShavadze Postgresql

Comment: `count(distinct objectnaam)` is not the *total amount of unique visits to planets*, but rather **the total amount of unique planets (by name), which was being visited**. -- Your tables' and columns' name are hard to read. Please translate them into english (either by replacing them, to provide a readable example), or give a translation/explanation below (in the question itself).

Comment: @pozs thank you for the explanation, i didn't see that. The question has been solved, but I'll definitely translate my future questions.

Comment: What is a `unique visit` ? what is a `non-unique visit` ?

Comment: @joop if someone visits the same planet twice, it should only be counted once, but if it's the moon, it should be counted twice

Comment: So, you want to count the number of (unique) *planets* that a person has visited, with the moon counting as two.

Comment: @joop yes, but the question has been solved

Comment: What should happen if a person visits the moon *three* times ?

Comment: @joop Then it should be counted 3 times

Comment: `... but if the planet is the moon (maan), then it should be counted twice ...` That is not in the question. Please learn how to formulate a question; in most cases formulating will almost bring you the solution.

Comment: @joop that's how it was formulated in the exercise, I found it unclear too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select sum(aantal_bezoeken) as aantal_bezoeken from
(select case 
        when objectnaam = 'Maan' then count(objectnaam)
        else count(distinct objectnaam)
   end as aantal_bezoeken
from klanten inner join deelnames on klanten.klantnr = deelnames.klantnr
         inner join reizen on deelnames.reisnr = reizen.reisnr
         inner join bezoeken on reizen.reisnr = bezoeken.reisnr
where klanten.klantnr = 121
group by objectnaam) as a
```

Comment: Yes thank you but is it possible without a subquery?

Comment: According to your example no.. Otherwise you can do it using Stored Procedure if you want one line Query.

Comment: If this one solved your problem then mark as answered